# Dio's get request returning incomplete data

Tags: flutter

I'm making a get request with the Dio library (https://pub.dev/packages/dio), but apparently it is not getting all the data in the coming json.

Here's the request:

[image]

This is the json that comes from it:

[image]

But this is the `Response` object I get from this request:

[image]:

Note how the `"headers"` field in the json has substantially more values than my `headers` field in `response.data`.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You are returning response without extract it's content. That's OK, but you need to extract the body from response where you are calling this method:

```
http.Response response = await _yourApi.getData();

if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    //Do what you want with body
    final body = response.body;
}
```